# Fullcalendar Scheduler (Event Overlap on Timeline Year)

Tags: jquery, arrays, fullcalendar, overlap

I have a lot of events on Fullcalendar Scheduler. On default, eventOverlap is `true`, but eventOverlap is not working on timelineYear.

This is the picture of my Fullcalendar Scheduler:
[image: picture]

I want to make them overlapping just like [agendaWeek](http://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaWeek) view. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can overlap, but only in vertical resource view. There is no easy way to make them overlap in horizontal resource view.

To see an example, take this demo and modify the resource for 'event 3' from 'b' to 'a', so that it overlaps with 'event 2':

http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.1/demos/vertical-resource-view.html

```
{ id: '3', resourceId: 'a', start: '2016-05-07T12:00:00', end: '2016-05-08T06:00:00', title: 'event 3' },
```